# Nib view differs from Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, nib

My nib

[image]

My Simulator. I can't understand why constraints don't work

[image]

I think code does not have influence, however see it below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if let headeView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? HeaderViewCell {

        //headeView.categoryLabel.text = "FFF"
        return headeView
    }




    return UIView()
}
```

Comment: I assume that what are you providing for viewer to give a useful answer ins not enough yet, could you elaborate? is there any code that might affect how the view should looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I start to make custom header, I saw video tutorial (https://youtu.be/gEoiiZZE6cw) where header based on UITableViewCell class. And you see result above.

I solved to try usual view and I got right result as below. Thanks all for answers
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the loaded view.

The best place to do this is `willDisplayHeaderView:forSection()`.

Also, do check your contraints setup.

Comment: I new in coding (less 1 year), do you mean I need set constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have given the constraints of the imageView correctly. may be top space leading and the height and width might do. And make the imageView's clip to bounds property to true.